# Check if an element is included in one or more lists

Tags: python, pandas

I would need help to include in one only command the following two steps:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(part_is_in, values = list_1)
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(part_is_in, values = list_2)
```

where `list_1` and `list_2` are lists of strings, and

```
def part_is_in(x, values):
    output = 'No'
    for val in values:
        if val in x:
            return 'Yes'
            break                
    return output
```

I would like to check if an element in `Col1` is in `list_1` and/or in `list_2`. Right now I am using a sequential update, but I would like to change the definition in order to check if a value can be in more lists. I am using the function above also to check element in other columns and I would need also to keep the case of only one list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(part_is_in, values = list_1 + list_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a function for that:

```
df[df['Col1'].isin(list1+list2)]['Col1']
```

This return elements in 'Col1' column than are in list1

Comment: Hi Cristian, thank you for your answer. I would need to check in both lists, 1 and 2.

Comment: I edited the answer for that, this way use vectorized numpy and is more fast than for in loop

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with very large dataset, you'd want to avoid using custom functions.

```
# Assume the columns you want to look at is included in cols 
new_cols = [f'{item}_1' for item in cols]
for old_col, new_col in zip(cols, new_cols):
    # where values(iterable) is whatever you want to check
    # this checks if each value in column is in values(iterable)
    # overwrite old_col if you can, if not this will add lots of new columns
    df[new_col] = df[old_col].map(lambda item: item in values) 

# This will call any() function on all the rows, 
# recall that each element in row x is True or False that represents if  
# the original value (from old_col at row x) is in values
df['result'] = df[new_cols].map(lambda row: any(row.values), axis=1)
```